# Error JSONObject no se pudo convertir a JSONArray

Tags: android-studio, jsonobject, jsonarray

Antes que nada quiero agradecer cualquier tipo ayuda que me puedan brindar, es la primer vez que estoy tratando de traer datos desde un servidor (MySQL) y guardarlo en mi aplicación con SQLite, he visto varios tutoriales y algo he entendido; tengo un error que según indica en el *Debug* no me permite cambiar el tipo de JSON; entiendo que en *stringRequest*, que es el *StringRequest* de Volley trae la consulta del servidor y luego en *onResponse* entro a recorrer la respuesta, pero es acá donde me sale el error y no se muy bien a que se refiera.

Este es mi código:

```
public void SincronizarCodigos(Context context){
    if(checkConexion(this)){
        // abrir conexión
        ConexionSQLiteHelper conex = new ConexionSQLiteHelper(this,"bd_datos",null,1);
        //Abrir base da datos en modo escritura
        final SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();
        String url = "http://192.168.0.131/servicio_web/web/obtener_gastos.php";

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest  = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("gastos");

                            for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++)
                            {
                                //JSONObject permite obtener un elemento dentro del JSONarray
                                JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                conex.GuardarCodigos(
                                        object.getString("idOperario"),
                                        object.getString("Operario"),
                                        object.getString("bloque"),
                                        object.getString("supervisor"),db);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("error",""+error);
                    }
                });
        MySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQue(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el error que me marca en el Debug:

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"estado":1,"gastos":[{"idOperario":"001","Operario":"OPERARIO 1","bloque":"BQ 001","supervisor":"SUPERVISOR 1"},{"idOperario":"002","Operario":"OPERARIO 2","bloque":"BQ 002","supervisor":"SUPERVISOR 2"},{"idOperario":"003","Operario":"OPERARIO 3","bloque":"BQ 003","supervisor":"SUPERVISOR 3"},{"idOperario":"004","Operario":"OPERARIO 4","bloque":"BQ 004","supervisor":"SUPERVISOR 4"},{"idOperario":"005","Operario":"OPERARIO 4","bloque":"BQ 005","supervisor":"SUPERVISOR 5"}]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
        at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
        at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
        at com.example.formsaide.MainActivityConsultaCodigos$2.onResponse(MainActivityConsultaCodigos.java:114)
        at com.example.formsaide.MainActivityConsultaCodigos$2.onResponse(MainActivityConsultaCodigos.java:110)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:82)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:29)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:819)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:210)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5943)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:817)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error que muestras dice que la cadena JSON es de tipo *JSONObject* y no puede ser convertida a *JSONArray*, también se muestra la cadena JSON que tienes:

```
{
    "estado":1,
    "gastos":
    [
        {
            "idOperario":"001",
            "Operario":"OPERARIO 1",
            "bloque":"BQ 001",
            "supervisor":"SUPERVISOR 1"
        },
        {
            "idOperario":"002",
            "Operario":"OPERARIO 2",
            "bloque":"BQ 002",
            "supervisor":"SUPERVISOR 2"
        },
        {
            "idOperario":"003",
            "Operario":"OPERARIO 3",
            "bloque":"BQ 003",
            "supervisor":"SUPERVISOR 3"
        },
        {
            "idOperario":"004",
            "Operario":"OPERARIO 4",
            "bloque":"BQ 004",
            "supervisor":"SUPERVISOR 4"
        },
        {
            "idOperario":"005",
            "Operario":"OPERARIO 4",
            "bloque":"BQ 005",
            "supervisor":"SUPERVISOR 5"
        }
    ]
}
```

En realidad es un Objeto y no un array, imagino que lo que quieres es cargar los gastos, para esto debes primero obtener el valor como objeto y posteriormente acceder a la propiedad "*gastos*" que tienes en el objeto.

Debes obtener el valor como JSONObject utilizando *JsonObjectRequest*, a continuación te pongo un ejemplo:

```
// Aquí instanciamos el *request* de tipo JSONObject
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://192.168.0.131/servicio_web/web/obtener_gastos.php", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            // Aquí obtenemos el array de gastos
            JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("gastos");
            for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++)
            {
                //JSONObject permite obtener un elemento dentro del JSONarray
                JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                conex.GuardarCodigos(
                        object.getString("idOperario"),
                        object.getString("Operario"),
                        object.getString("bloque"),                    
                        object.getString("supervisor"),db);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // TODO: Handle error

    }
});
```

[Aquí](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request) te dejo la documentación para que le eches un ojo.

Comment: Tienes un *typo* en esta linea: `JSONArray array = objeto = objeto.getJSONArray("gastos");`, me refiero a `objeto =`. Decir también que Volley tiene métodos específicos según el tipo de respuesta, si la respuesta es un JSONObject es mejor usar ese tipo de respuesta en vez de String, así no hay que hacer conversión posterior. Si fuese un JSONArray lo mismo, Volley tiene un tipo de respuesta de esa clase.

Comment: Tienes razón @A.Cedano, corregí la respuesta gracias por la observación. ;)

Comment: @FerneyGuerrero, al parecer faltaba pasar un parámetro como null al instanciar el `JsonObjectRequest`, lo corregí en mi respuesta, por favor prueba con la corrección que realicé. ;)

Comment: Si era eso, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Primeramente te falta un parámetro al realizar la petición, debe ser:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,  url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Ahora si revisas el mensaje de error y tu respuesta indica que tratas de convertir un valor de tipo `JSONObject` a `JSONArray`

> org.json.JSONException: Value {......} of type org.json.JSONObject
> cannot be converted to JSONArray

Recuerda que la información `JSON` puede estar definida como :

- Si el json inicia con `{` se considera como objeto Json.
- Si el json inicia con `[` es considerado como arreglo Json.

y esta es tu respuesta, un `JSONObject` que contiene un `JSONArray` y dentro varios `JSONObject`:

```
{
    "estado": 1,
    "gastos": [{
        "idOperario": "001",
        "Operario": "OPERARIO 1",
        "bloque": "BQ 001",
        "supervisor": "SUPERVISOR 1"
    }, {
        "idOperario": "002",
        "Operario": "OPERARIO 2",
        "bloque": "BQ 002",
        "supervisor": "SUPERVISOR 2"
    }, {
        "idOperario": "003",
        "Operario": "OPERARIO 3",
        "bloque": "BQ 003",
        "supervisor": "SUPERVISOR 3"
    }, {
        "idOperario": "004",
        "Operario": "OPERARIO 4",
        "bloque": "BQ 004",
        "supervisor": "SUPERVISOR 4"
    }, {
        "idOperario": "005",
        "Operario": "OPERARIO 4",
        "bloque": "BQ 005",
        "supervisor": "SUPERVISOR 5"
    }]
}
```

Por lo tanto debes obtener primeramente el `JSONObject` y posteriormente obtener el `JSONArray` llamado "gastos" para iterar por cada uno de sus `JSONObject` y guardar sus valores en la base de datos:

```
try {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response); 
    JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("gastos");
    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++){
        object = array.getJSONObject(i);
        
          conex.GuardarCodigos(
                object.getString("idOperario"),
                object.getString("Operario"),
                object.getString("bloque"),
                object.getString("supervisor"),db);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```